# Find minimal value of $\left(2-x\right)\left(2-y\right)\left(2-z\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, roots, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $x,y,z>0$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$. Find minimal value of $$\left(2-x\right)\left(2-y\right)\left(2-z\right)$$

I thought the equality occurs at $x = y = z = 1$ (then it is easy), but the fact is $x = y = \frac{1}{3}; z = \frac{5}{3}$. So I just thought of using $uvw$, but I am not allowed to use it during my exam. Because of the equality I cannot use AMGM, Cauchy-Schwarz, etc.

I tried to use Mixing-Variables, but I failed. Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with AM-GM and CS? Lagrange multipliers then?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Lagrange multiplier method is a deeper method than $uvw$, so I think it's not supposed to be used.

Comment: @Shubhrajit Bhattacharya What do you say?  "Lagrange multiplier method is a deep method." It's one of methods for the inequalities proofs. Not more.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Obviously Lagrange Multiplier Method is deep, its proof requires much knowledge in multidimensional real analysis.

Comment: @Shubhrajit Bhattacharya I think, the proof of LM is trivial. It's enough to understand the idea. Read please this proof. To use LM it's a big problem in the general.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I've read your proof. It's brilliant. I was wrong and I apologize for what I said about $uvw$ method.

Answer (score 3):

Wlog $z\le 1$ because the variables cannot all be $\ge1$.
For fixed $z$, we want to minimize $(2-x)(2-y)$ under a constraint $x^2+y^2=3-z^2$, which is a constant between $2$ and $3$.

Now
$$ \begin{align}(2-x)(2-y)&=4-2(x+y)+xy\\&=4-2(x+y)+\frac12(x+y)^2-\frac{3-z^2}2\\
&=\frac12\left(x+y-2\right)^2+2-\frac{3-z^2}2
\\ &\ge2-\frac{3-z^2}2\\&=\frac{z^2+1}2
\end{align}$$
with equality iff $x+y=2$. Note that this makes $x^2+y^2=x^2+(2-x)^2=4-4x+2x^2=2(x-1)^2+2$, i.e., we can always find such $x,y$ when $z\le 1$ and $x^2+y^2=3-z^2\in [2,3]$.
So we want to minimize $\frac{z^2+1}2\cdot(2-z)=\frac12(2-z+2z^2-z^3)$ with $0<z\le1$.
The derivative of this cubic is $-3z^2+4z-1=(z-1)(1-3z)$, so we find the desired minimum at $z=\frac13$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x=y=\frac{1}{3}$ and $z=\frac{5}{3}$ we obtain a value $\frac{25}{27}.$

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, the condition gives $$3u^2-2v^2=1$$ and does not depend on $w^3$, which says that we need to find a minimum of the linear function of $w^3$, which happens in our case for the maximal value of $w^3$.

Now, $x$, $y$ and $z$ they are roots of the equation:
$$(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)=0$$ or
$$t^3-3ut^2+3v^2t=w^3,$$ which says that a graph of $f(t)=t^3-3ut^2+3v^2t$ and a graph of $g(t)=w^3$ have three common points.

Now, $$f'(t)=3t^2-6ut+3v^2=3(t^2-2ut+v^2),$$ which gives
$$t_{max}=u-\sqrt{u^2-v^2}>0$$ and $$t_{min}=u+\sqrt{u^2-v^2}>0.$$
Also, we see that $f(0)=0$.

Now, we can draw a graph of $f$ and we see that $w^3$ gets a maximal value, when $g$ is a tangent line to graph of $f$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=x$.

Thus, $z=\sqrt{3-2x^2},$ where $0<x<\sqrt{1.5}$ and we need to prove that
$$(2-x)^2(2-\sqrt{3-2x^2})\geq\frac{25}{27}$$ or
$$\frac{191}{27}-8x+2x^2\geq(2-x)^2\sqrt{3-2x^2}$$ or
$$(3x-1)^2(162x^4-1188x^3+3159x^2-3594x+1489)\geq0$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$162x^4-1188x^3+3159x^2-3594x+1489\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$162x^4-1188x^3+3159x^2-3594x+1489\geq$$
$$\geq162x^4-1188x^3+3158x^2-3594x+1488=$$
$$=2(81x^4-594x^3+1579x^2-1797x+744)=$$
$$=2\left((9x^2-33x+27)^2+4x^2-15x+15\right)>0.$$
Now we see that  $\frac{25}{27}$ is a minimal value of the expression $\prod\limits_{cyc}(2-x)$ for any reals $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=3.$

Comment: @Shubhrajit Bhattacharya About which $uvw$ do you say? See please my post and I am ready to explain if something is not clear.

Comment: Sir i actually do not know why the condition does not depend on $w^3$ then we need to find minimal of linear function $w^3$ and when $w^3$ gets a maximal value then we have equality case of two variables.

Comment: I know uvw is very strong but a little is hard to understand with me. I would be glad to able to understand it.

Comment: @user774564 Any symmetric polynomial of three variables we can write as polynomial of three variables $u$, $v^2$ and $w^3$. Also, the condition it's $3u^2-2v^2=1$, which does not depend on $w^3$. Just see the condition.

Comment: And why $g$ is tangent line to graph of $f$ we have equality case of two variables?

Comment: @user774564 Because we'll obtain a double point in the touching point.

Comment: Sir. Pls explaining for me the 6th line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108231/discussion-between-user774564-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 1):

From [Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h471599p2640533) on AoPS:

Without loss of generality $x \ge y \ge z > 0$, so that $z \le 1$. We have
$$
2(2-x)(2-y) = (x+y-2)^2 +4 - x^2-y^2 \ge 4 - x^2 - y^2  = 1+z^2
$$
and therefore
$$
 (2-x)(2-y)(2-z) \ge \frac 1 2 (1+z^2)(2-z) =: f(z) \, .
$$
An elementary calculation shows that the minimum of $f$ on $[0, 1]$ is $f(1/3) = 25/27$, i.e.
$$
(2-x)(2-y)(2-z) \ge \frac{25}{27} \, .
$$
Equality holds if $(x, y, z)$ is a permutation of $(5/3, 1/3, 1/3)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a straight-forward solution with Lagrange multipliers. It is more convenient to examine the (continuous) function
$$
 f(x, y, z) = (2-x)(2-y)(2-z)
$$
on the (compact) set $K = \{ (x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2 = 3 \}$ first, without the restriction to positive arguments.

$f$ attains both minimum and maximum on $K$, and the Lagrange method gives that at the extremal points
$$
 -(2-y)(2-z) = \lambda 2x \\
 -(2-x)(2-z) = \lambda 2y \\
 -(2-x)(2-y) = \lambda 2z 
$$
for some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. We see that $\lambda$ cannot be zero, so that
$$
 x(2-x) = y(2-y) = z(2-z) =: \alpha \, ,
$$
i.e. $x, y, z$ are all solutions of the quadratic equation $t^2 - 2t + \alpha = 0$. It follows that any two of them are equal or add to $2$. So we have two possible cases:

1. $x=y=z$. Then necessarily $x=y=z = \pm 1$.
2. Up to a permutation, $x=y=2-z$. Substituting that into $x^2+y^2+z^2$ gives
   $$
    3 = 2x^2 + (2-x)^2 = 3x^2 -4x + 4 \iff (3x-1)(x-1) = 0 \, .
   $$
   If $x=1$ then (again) $x=y=z=\pm 1$. Otherwise $(x, y, z) = (1/3, 1/3, 5/3)$.

So the only possible extremal values of $f$ on $K$ are
$$
\begin{align}
 f(1, 1, 1) &= 1 \, \\
 f(-1, -1, -1) &= 27 \, \\
 f(1/3, 1/3, 5/3) &= 25/27 \, ,
\end{align}
$$
and we conclude that $25/27$ is the minimum.

This is also the mimimum for the given problem because it is attained at a point with $x, y, z > 0$.